# Canvas 1 should resize to window, Canvas 2 should be fixed in size

Tags: html, css, canvas

I have two canvas elements (canvas1 and canvas2). "canvas1" should resize to fit the window, this is working. However "canvas2" should remain fixed in size. This is not working, since this canvas is also resizing to fit the window. How te change my code that I get the desired result?

I have the following (simplified) HTML code:

```
<script>
{% block jquery %}

$(document).ready(function(){
    showImage();
});

function showImage(){
    var c = document.getElementById('canvas2')
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '{{STATIC_URL}}/static/my_app/img/my_image.png' 
    c.width = 100
    c.height = 100
    img.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0, img.width, img.height);
    }
}
{% endblock %}
</script>

{% block content %}
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'collectorField/css/style.css' %}">

<canvas id="canvas1" width="1000" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

<canvas id="canvas2" width="100" height="100" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

{% endblock %}
```

The linked CSS style sheet (style.css) is defined as follows:

```
canvas {
  background-color: white; 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Could you remove the templating code and turn this into a working snippet? I also don't really see any code for `canvas1` going fullscreen, so I can't see why that is working. The second canvas might also have to do with `img.width` not being `img.naturalWidth`, so it might be `0`? Try just painting it will a fill to see if your basics work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is actually quitte simple, sorry to bother you all.

I changed my style.css file as follows:

```
#canvas1 {
  background-color: white; 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

So instead of applying to all canvas elements it only applies to "canvas1".